# How could I get a single d3 selection (or array of dom elements) that includes all the exiting elements as well as new and existing ones?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a stacked bar chart to animate correctly as bars come and go. There's probably a good example of this somewhere (I'll ask as a separate question: [How to correctly transition stacked bars in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286170/how-to-correctly-transition-stacked-bars-in-d3-js)), but the examples I'm finding don't show transitions with individual stack elements exiting and entering.

My idea is to make a tween function that sets the y of each bar to the top of the of the bar beneath it. I want to make sure that as bars are exiting, they drag down the bars above them, and as they're entering, they push up the bars above them. And I don't want any gaps or overlaps midway through the transition.

But to get this to work, I would ideally have a list of all the bars--exiting, entering, existing--in order, and I would be able to tell which category each bar belonged to. So, I could kludge something together, assembling a single array from  `rects`, `rects.enter()`, and `rects.exit()` (after something like

```
rects = d3.selectAll('g.barGroups').selectAll('rects').data(newData)
```

.)
But there's got to be a better way.

Comment: So, for that kludgy idea: `rects.enter().append('rect').attr('from','enter'); rects.exit().attr('from','exit'); allRects = d3.selectAll('g.barGroups').selectAll('rects');` That would give me the list I need for transitioning, and then I could go back and remove elements from `rects.exit()` after that.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967)?

Comment: I had. I wasn't sure if it would work because it doesn't explicitly handle entering and exiting stack bars. Someone offered a fiddle based on this one but that does what I want (in my more direct version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286170/how-to-correctly-transition-stacked-bars-in-d3-js?noredirect=1#comment46795191_29286170): http://jsfiddle.net/pqytxc6L/13/