# How to correctly transition stacked bars in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a stacked bar chart to animate correctly as bars come and go. There's probably a good example of this somewhere (maybe I'll ask as a separate question), but the examples I'm finding don't show transitions with individual stack elements exiting and entering I want to make sure that as bars are exiting, they drag down the bars above them, and as they're entering, they push up the bars above them. And I don't want any gaps or overlaps midway through the transition.

Can anyone point me to an example that does this?

---

**Correcting my wrong-headed question:**
Ashitaka answered the question with a helpful jsfiddle. His answer prompted me to look at the [d3 stack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#_stack) more closely, where I read:

> In the simplest case, layers is a two-dimensional array of values. All of the 2nd-dimensional arrays must be the same length.

So, I concluded I was going about this all wrong. I shouldn't have been trying to remove stack bars at all. If bars in my data were going to disappear, I should leave them in the data and change their height to zero. That way the transitions work great. I haven't yet had to deal with new bars appearing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pqytxc6L/13/

Took me a lot of work to make this (for my current job). Enjoy!

Comment: Wow. This looks great. How would you feel about offering some commentary about the strategies you used to manage the transitions? Also, if you feel like putting it in as an answer, then I could check it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Sure. I avoided writing an answer because I was sure it would take me a really long time. I'll try writing a clear explanation in a few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One confusing aspect of transitioning stacked charts (and working with SVG in general) is that the coordinate system origin is at the top-left corner, which means that y increases downwards.

First, our data should have 2 y related attributes:

- `y`, the height of the bar
- And `y0`, the baseline or the y position of the bar when it's on top of other bars. This should be calculated by `d3.layout.stack()`.

Then, we should create 2 scales:

- One for height, which works exactly as expected:

  ```
  var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxStackY])
    .range([0, height]);
  ```
- And one for the y position, which works in the reverse way:

  ```
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, maxStackY])
    .range([height, 0]);
  ```

With these two scales, we can create some functions to calculate the appropriate y positions and heights of our bars:

```
var barBaseY = function (d) { return yScale(d.y0); };

var barTopY = function (d) { return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); };

var barHeight = function (d) { return heightScale(d.y); };
```

Next, it's critical that we create a [key function](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#key) so that elements are bound to the correct data:

```
var joinKey = function (d) { return d.name; };
```

Without this function D3 would join the data using its index, which would break everything.

Now, to remove or add a set of bars from the stack, we take these steps:

1. Recalculate the stack:

   ```
   var newStack = stack(enabledSeries());
   ```
2. Join the new stack with the current selection of layers with the [data function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

   ```
   layers = layers.data(newStack, joinKey);
   ```

   With our key function, D3 determines the bars that are to be added, removed or updated.
3. Access the appropriate bars:

   - `layers.enter()` contains the "enter selection", that is, the new set of bars to be added.
   - `layers.exit()` contains the "exit selection", that is, the set of bars to be removed.
   - And simply `layers` contains the "update selection", that is, the bars that are to be updated. However, [after enter.append the "update selection" is modified to contain both entering and updating elements](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#enter-update). This has changed in D3 v4 though.
4. Animate the bars:

   - For added bars, we create them with `height` 0 and `y` position `barBaseY`.
     Then we animate all the bars' `height` and `y` attributes.
   - For removed bars, we animate them to `height` 0 and `y` position `barBaseY`, the exact opposite of adding bars. Then we animate all the remaining bars' `height` and `y` attributes. D3 is smart enough to render all these animations at the same time.

Here's [a pared down version of the stacked chart I linked to in my first comment](http://jsfiddle.net/e0vehs1q/1/).

And [here's a visual explanation of why you have to animate both `y` and `height` attributes to simulate a bar diminishing in size "going down"](http://bl.ocks.org/guilhermesimoes/be6b8be8a3e8dc2b70e2).

Comment: I'm attempting something similar, but after doing my `layers = layers.data(newStack, joinKey)` call my exit and enter groups are empty (despite them saying they have length 6). Would you be able to take a look at my question and see if I'm missing something obvious? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683729/d3-update-existing-stack-data-when-selecting-deselecting-series

Comment: Would you be able to to create a jsfiddle so we could see the working code? That would help tremendously.

Comment: Hey @Ashitaka I posted a question regarding an issue i am running into with D3 v4, do you mind taking a look at it and steering me in the correct direction?